# Как обозначить тип аргумента функции "любая последовательность"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции, типы-данных

Есть функция:

```
def func(a: tuple):
    pass
```

Мне нужно, чтобы аргумент a принимал любую стандартную последовательность (tuple, list, set). Как указать, что тип аргумента - любая последовательность (в примере выше указано, что аргумент может быть только кортежем).
Я понимаю, что можно и не указывать, но мне нужно это указать, чтобы позже не путаться в коде.
Спасибо за конструктивные ответы.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1952464/7485582

Comment: Ясно, спасибо..

Comment: в примере выше указано не то, что аргумент "может быть только кортежем", а то, что кортеж _ожидается_ автором функции в виде аргумента. Если внутри функции не будет явной проверки на тип аргумента, то вы можете в нее передавать все, что захотите, вне зависимости от того, что у вас написано в скобках.

Comment: Согласен, что ожидается тип кортеж, а не требуется. После джавы не привык ещё.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если нужны только перечисленные типы, то делайте `Union` из трех перечисленных типов:

```
from typing import Union


def func(a: Union[tuple, list, set]):
    pass
```

Если допустимы любые типы, которые поддерживают итерацию (в том числе и строки и генераторы/итераторы), то можно использовать `Iterable`:

```
from typing import Iterable


def func(a: Iterable):
    pass
```